# VLC Command Line Flag --loop from Batch File Not Working

Tags: batch-file, vlc-media-player

I used to have a batch file that started a playlist in VLC, set to loop indefinitely.

Now though, I'm not sure if I have messed it up at some point or a new version of VLC has rendered it obsolete, but VLC no longer opens set to loop.

```
echo
rem choice /c YN /n /d Y /t 120
taskkill /im vlc.exe

ping localhost -n 5 > nul  
start /max "" "myplaylist.pls" --loop
```

Does the command flag work for the file type .pls or would I have to open VLC first before loading the playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below works for me, although taskkill no longer seems to work as it did previously. The CMD window says the kill command was successfully sent, but VLC doesn't close.

```
﻿﻿echo
rem choice /c YN /n /d Y /t 120
taskkill /im vlc.exe

ping localhost -n 10 > nul  
start /max "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --loop -vvv myplaylist.pls
```